# syntax error in printing String

Tags: python-2.7

I want to print the pattern

```
hello!
10
8
6
4
2
```

I have written the following code

```
print "Hello!";
num=10;
while(num>=2)
   print num;
   num-=2;
```

Upon execution it is showing `syntax error at line 1..`

Comment: You need a colon after while condition `while num >= 2:`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use semicolons in Python code. There are 2 ways to do this.

1) Using While Loop -

```
print "Hello!"
num = 10
while num >= 2:
    print num
    num -= 2
```

2) Using For loop -

```
print "Hello!"
for i in range(10, 1,-2):
    print i
```